How to change the text of the "OK" button of the popup that displays the dropdown_search package in Flutter
How to change the text of the "OK" button of the popup that shows the dropdown_search package in Flutter, in Multi-selection mode.
See image
DropdownSearch<String>.multiSelection(
    popupProps: PopupPropsMultiSelection.menu(
        showSearchBox: false,
        showSelectedItems: false,
        fit: FlexFit.loose,
    ),
)

Package: https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search
I have not found in the documentation any way to change this text.
Solution
final _popupCustomValidationKey =
            GlobalKey<DropdownSearchState<String>>();

DropdownSearch<String>.multiSelection(
    key: _popupCustomValidationKey,
    popupProps: PopupPropsMultiSelection.menu(
        showSearchBox: false,
        showSelectedItems: false,
        fit: FlexFit.loose,
        validationWidgetBuilder: (context, items) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _popupCustomValidationKey.currentState?
                 .changeSelectedItems(items);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }, 
              child: Text("Your text"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
    ),
)


you have just to use _popupCustomValidationKey.currentState?.popupOnValidate()

You can't modify actual text on that button, but it's possible to modify button creation.
This is how button created: source code
You can provide similar method as validationBuilder parameter to you popupProps. Like this:
DropdownSearch<String>.multiSelection(
  popupProps: PopupPropsMultiSelection.menu(
    showSearchBox: false,
    showSelectedItems: false,
    fit: FlexFit.loose,
    validationBuilder: (context, items) => Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // do something here with items
            // Also you can close dialog here with
            // Navigator.pop(context);
            // default implementation does 2 things:
            // 1. calls onChanged method with items as parameter
            // 2. Closes popup with Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text("Your text"),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

Pay attention to onPressed – you will have to provide actual logic of closing this menu and manipulate chosen items. I left a comment with suggestion and more or less default implementation.

this worksonPressed: () { _popupCustomValidationKey.currentState                                     ?.changeSelectedItems(items);                                 Navigator.pop(context);}

@70NY this is will do it for you : _popupCustomValidationKey.currentState?.popupOnValidate()

This code will help you to resolve the issue
DropdownSearch<String>.multiSelection(
  popupProps: PopupPropsMultiSelection.menu(
    showSearchBox: false,
    showSelectedItems: false,
    fit: FlexFit.loose,
    dialogProps: DialogPropsMultiSelection(
      validationMultiSelectionButton: (context, controller) {
        return ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            controller.closePopup();
          },
          child: Text("Confirm"), 
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
)

